# SVN. Не могу соединится с хранилищем

Tags: svn, repository

Как устранить ошибку:

> SVN test failed!
>
> Cause:
>
> org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>
> svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file://localhost/D:/SVN_SUBST/rad_test_project/TEST_RAD'
>
> svn: E125006: 'D:\SVN_SUBST\db\format' contains invalid filesystem format option 'addressing logical'
>
> Cause:
>
> svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>
> svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file://localhost/D:/SVN_SUBST/rad_test_project/TEST_RAD'
>
> svn: E125006: 'D:\SVN_SUBST\db\format' contains invalid filesystem format option 'addressing logical'

Каталог "D:\SVN_SUBST" примаплен так же как виртуальный через subst. Версия SVN 1.9.

Comment: скорее всего у вас клиент старой верси (до 1.9). что показывает svn --version?

Comment: С SVN только начинаю работать и еще не все знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, название утилиты или приложения, где необходимо посмотреть версию?

Comment: svn --version в консоли

Comment: svn, version 1.9.5. все честно.

Comment: а SVN test failed! вы откуда получаете? из консоли? или из какого-нибудь jenkins?

Comment: Ошибку получаю из прикладухи при создании проекта. В свойсвтах проекта необходимо указать SVN как основной параметр.

Comment: Значит к вашей прикладухе прилинкована внутри старая версия svn.